# ATI propietary drivers renaming libGL.so

Tags: c++, opengl, makefile, cmake, linux-mint

I recently re-installed linux (mint 17) and after I built and ran my project it complained about failing to load `swrast`. I figured I'd have to install the ati drivers and indeed it fixed the issue:

```
Graphics:  Card: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD/ATI] Oland XT [Radeon HD 8670 / R7 250] bus-    ID: 01:00.0 
X.Org: 1.15.1 driver: fglrx Resolution: 1920x1080@60.0hz 
GLX Renderer: AMD Radeon R7 200 Series GLX Version: 4.4.13283 - CPC 14.501.1003 Direct Rendering: Yes
```

Problem I'm having now is that I can't build the project anymore, as make can't find `libGL.so`

```
No rule to make target `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so
```

Had a look and there seems to be a renamed version, I don't know what's going on...

```
/usr/lib/FGL.renamed.libGL.so.1.2
/usr/lib/libGL.so
/usr/lib/libGL.so.1
/usr/lib/libGL.so.1.2
/usr/lib/fglrx/fglrx-libGL.so.1.2
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libGL.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1.2
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/fglrx/fglrx-libGL.so.1.2
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/mesa/FGL.renamed.libGL.so.1.2.0
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/FGL.renamed.libGL.so.1.2.0
```

I think I have to create some links but I don't know which. I've done it in the past and it messed up the ati installation.

Comment: Why can't you just use `/usr/lib/libGL.so`? It is standard name linker expects when you request `-lGL`.

Comment: How do I do that? I'm not including it myself glfw is. Shouldn't it just use the standard one?

Comment: `No rule to make target` means your makefile depends on exactly that file. Strictly speaking you shouldn't depend on any .so at all, rebuilding program after dynamic libraries changes isn't good idea; check your makefile and remove this dependency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it to work. I realized netbeans hadn't actually regenerated my make file after I installed the ati drivers and I think it was trying to pull in dependencies from the old location. Sure the drivers still do some funky things but at least I think they create their own symlink. I deleted the project and re-imported it and it works as it should now.

Answer (score 2):

> Had a look and there seems to be a renamed version, I don't know what's going on...

The `libGL.so` is part of the GPU drivers (in fact it contains the whole OpenGL implementation). This is different from Windows, where the `opengl32.dll` provides hooks for the driver to attach itself to. Technically it was preferable to have this hooking mechanism in Linux as well, but unfortunately we don't.

To soften up the situation, Linux distribution's package manager normally install the driver's `libGL.so` to an isolated directory and create a symlink to it in `/usr/lib/`. The proprietary driver's binary packages not installed by the distributions' package managers for some reason don't follow that convention and just clobber over this structure.

Honestly, it would have been far easier to implement that hooking mechanism in the meantime, rather than creating these symlink kludges.

Comment: Completely agree with you. Thanks for answering.